# Why does my grep command output "--" between some lines?

Tags: grep, fasta

I have a fasta file like the test one here:

```
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:3:1106:16404:19663 1:N:0:GCCAAT
CCTAGCACCATGATTTAATGTTTCTTTTGTACGTTCTTTCTTTGGAAACTGCACTTGTTGCAACCTTGCAAGCCATATAAACACATTTCAGATATAAGGCT
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:3:1106:16404:19663 2:N:0:GCCAAT
AAAACATAAATTTGAGCTTGACAAAAATTAAAAATGAGCCCAGCCTTATATCTGAAATGTGTTTATATGGCTTGCAAGGTTGCAACAAGTGCAGTTTCCAA
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:4:1304:10466:100132 1:N:0:GCCAAT
ATATTTGAATTATCAGAAATAAACACAAAGAAAACCTAGAACAGATAATTTCTTCCACATTATTGATCAGATACAGATTTCAAGGGTACCGTTGTGAATTG
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:4:1304:10466:100132 2:N:0:GCCAAT
AAACGATTGATAGATCTATTTGCATTATAAAAACATTAAAAAAACAAAATACTGATTAAATGTCGTCTTTCTATTCCACAATTTTATAGATCTCACTGTAT
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:4:1307:12056:64030 1:N:0:GCCAAT
CTTACTTTGCCTCTCTCAGCCAATGTCTCCTGAGTCTAATTTTTTGGAGGCTAAGCTATGAGCTAATGATGGGTTCCATTTGGGGCCAATGCTTCAGCCTG
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:4:1307:12056:64030 2:N:0:GCCAAT
CTATTAGTTCTTATCTTTGCCTGCAAATATAAGACTAGCGCTTGAGTAGCTGACAGAGACAAAGTAAGCTGGAGTGTTTATCACCTGGTCACTCCAATTGT
```

When i type in a simple grep command like:

```
grep -B1 "CTT" test.fasta
```

I get a really strange output in which "--" is sometimes placed on a newline above the grep hit like so:

```
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:4:1304:10466:100132 2:N:0:GCCAAT
AAACGATTGATAGATCTATTTGCATTATAAAAACATTAAAAAAACAAAATACTGATTAAATGTCGTCTTTCTATTCCACAATTTTATAGATCTCACTGTAT
--
>HWI-D00196:168:C66U5ANXX:4:1307:12056:64030 2:N:0:GCCAAT
CTATTAGTTCTTATCTTTGCCTGCAAATATAAGACTAGCGCTTGAGTAGCTGACAGAGACAAAGTAAGCTGGAGTGTTTATCACCTGGTCACTCCAATTGT
```

I can't figure out why some fasta entries have this and others don't. I don't get this problem when i remove the -B1. I can remove those lines from my file with a `grep -v "--"` statement, but I'd really like to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for one line of leading context by using the `-B1` option. This means grep will display both the line which matched and the line directly before it. Each match will be separated by `--` on a line by itself as shown below:

```
$ man grep | grep -B1 context
     -A num, --after-context=num
             Print num lines of trailing context after each match.  See also
--
     -B num, --before-context=num
             Print num lines of leading context before each match.  See also
--
     -C[num, --context=num]
             Print num lines of leading and trailing context surrounding each
--
     --context[=num]
             Print num lines of leading and trailing context.  The default is
```

The reason you aren't seeing `--` between every match is that the context is only displayed above a sequence of consecutive matches. So see the following example:

```
seq 13 | grep -B1 1
1
--
9
10
11
12
13
```

The seq command produces all the numbers between 1 and 13. Only the first line and the lines from 10 on contain a 1, so you see the 1 in its own group, then `--`, then the one line context, then the group of consecutive matching lines.

Comment: Thanks @chthonicdaemon, my confusion is to why only **some** matches are separated by `--` and others are not

Comment: The `--` will only be put in if there are non-consecutive matches. I'll update my answer.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, you can remove the inter-match separators using eg `grep -B1 "CTT" test.fasta | grep -v ^--`.

Answer (score 0):

`GREP_COLORS` section of the grep manpage says :

> Specifies the colors and  other  attributes  used  to  highlight various  > parts  of  the  output.  Its value is a colon-separated list
>   of capabilities that defaults to
>   ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36  with  the  rv and
>   ne boolean capabilities omitted  (i.e.,  false).

and

> se=36
>   SGR substring for separators that  are  inserted  between
>   selected  line  fields  (:), between context line fields, (-), and
>   between groups of adjacent  lines  when  nonzero context  is 
>   specified  (--).  The default is a cyan text foreground over the
>   terminal's default background.

Consider file sample.txt :

```
$cat sample.txt
ABBB
AAB
AAB
S
S
S
AABB
ABAA
BAA
CCC
$grep -B2 'AAB' sample.txt
ABBB
AAB
AAB
--
S
S
AABB
```

Here `--` is the way of `grep` to tell you that `AAB` before `--` and `S` after `--` are not adjacent lines in the actual file.